# not able to pass data from local swf to remote PHP

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

I am working on a Flash file where I need to POST data from my local swf to a PHP file on my live server.

I use code from following url:

http://tush.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/actionscript-3-using-urlloader-to-send-and-load-server-variables/

The remote PHP file is getting called but I could not get data in POST, neither in GET method. Seems like data is not getting POSTed to my remote PHP file from the local swf.

Please guide.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can POST to a local file, then you should check if your server is open to do these sorts of things. (Either check the Apache config or PHP config).

You might also want to check `Security.allowDomain("your url");` which is in `flash.system.Security;`

Comment: Security.allowDomain("my live url"); doesn't seem to work in my case :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you can't do it.

You can't cross domains like this.  If you're running your SWF locally, you can only ever talk to local resources.  If you're running it from a server, you can talk to other network resources through the use of cross-domain policy.

Comment: hi John. thanks for the response. I tried running the swf from my live server too but same thing happens. how can i use cross-domain policy that you are talking about ?

Comment: Whatever server you're attempting to pull data from must have a cross-domain policy set up.  Here's more info:  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html

If it isn't your server, you may just be out of luck.  You'd need to create a proxy system on a server you do own.

However, all of this is speculation.  You should get error messages in your debug console.  They didn't help you find your issue?

Comment: the crossdomain.xml seems to have solved my problem, in it's most generous form though - <allow-access-from domain="*"/>

Comment: That just means that anybody can talk to your server.  Generally, not a big deal.

This kind of file is designed to discourage creation of things like automated port sniffers, that could act as a bridge across something like a corporate firewall.  It is generally best to only allow-access-from-domain on your own domain, but there are definitely situations where you want to open it up further.